# Error when converting to Date time (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert the following date string into datetime object. But for some reason it does not work. Any idea what the issue could be ?

```
string dt = "22-08-2018 16:53:00:000";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

// Shaiz

Answer (score 0):

The input string seems wrong. With "22-08-2018 16:53:00.000" it will work. Note the use of "." to separate seconds and milliseconds

Comment: I tried what you suggested and i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may depend on the current culture.  The value in your example appears to be day-month-year, and if attempting to convert in the "en-US" culture (for example), it will produce the `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`
If you *know* what the format of the datetime string will be, you can "force" it into the conversion.  Here's a unit test using your example input string:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        var dtFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
        dtFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"; // force to day-month-year

        string dt = "22-08-2018 16:53:00.000";
        var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt, dtFormat);

        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2018, 08, 22, 16, 53, 0), date);
    }
```

Comment: Your test works but when i try to change the pattern to " dtFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";"  which gives me the same error

Comment: check the comment to your OP by @Gianlucca - that's probably the way to go

Comment: I changed the date format from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd which gave me the same error.